# Why does my container with ID not change from Blue to Red in the Document.ready anonymous function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a form that is generated by our website provider. It has an ID that I have accessed. IN the css I have the color as blue and it is hidden. I have code in the document.ready event on click to center the form in the window. . It centers perfect thanks to stackoverflow. I then added to the click event to change the color to red.  When I activate the code by clicking the  tag in the document the form is still blue. I don't care about the color in particular, but I am trying to learn how to manipulate other elements in the form like adding a close button later.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a").click(function () {
            var windowWidth
            var windowHeight
            var formWidth
            var formHeight
            var placementHeight
            var placementWidth
            $("#custom-form-1451559841907633284-p").attr('style', 'display:block;');
            windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
            windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
            formWidth = $('#custom-form-1451559841907633284-p').width();
            formHeight = $('#custom-form-1451559841907633284-p').height();
            placementHeight = (windowHeight - formHeight) / 2;
            placementWidth = (windowWidth - formWidth) / 2;
            $('#custom-form-1451559841907633284-p').css("top", placementHeight);
            $('#custom-form-1451559841907633284-p').css("left", placementWidth);
            $('custom-form-1451559841907633284-p').css('background-color', 'red');
            $('#custom-form-1451559841907633284-p').css('z-Index', '30');
        }); //end of a anchor click
        window.console.log("test of nested anonymous function");
    });
</script>
```

CSS

```
#custom-form-1451559841907633284-p
{
    position: fixed; 
    display: none;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: A better way would be using `addClass` on click. This way, you can reduce the line of codes and bypass the nitty-gritty of adding each css lines

Comment: Thank you. I have a lot do digest(learn). I will look at this today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using a wrong selector in this line:

> $('custom-form-1451559841907633284-p').css('background-color', 'red');

you forgot the hash in front of **custom-form-1451559841907633284-p**, just replace that line with the following:

> $("#custom-form-1451559841907633284-p").css("background-color", "red");

you can see a working example here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-lichterman-vus5g

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:

```js
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $("a").click(function() {
       var $form = $("#custom-form-1451559841907633284-p");
       var windowWidth;
       var windowHeight;
       var formWidth;
       var formHeight;
       var placementHeight;
       var placementWidth;
       $form.attr('style', 'display:block;');
       windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
       windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
       formWidth = $form.width();
       formHeight = $form.height();
       placementHeight = (windowHeight - formHeight) / 2;
       placementWidth = (windowWidth - formWidth) / 2;
       $form.css("top", placementHeight);
       $form.css("left", placementWidth);
       $form.css('background-color', 'red');
       $form.css('z-Index', '30');
     }); //end of a anchor click
     window.console.log("test of nested anonymous function");
   });
```

```css
#custom-form-1451559841907633284-p {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="custom-form-1451559841907633284-p">
  <br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Text">
  <br>
</form>
<a href="#">Click</a>
```

Comment: thank you. I see you assigned the id to a variable. I guess a lot less likely to have errors in such long ids.

Comment: My pleasure. :)